# Why can't I log in to superuser with lynx?

Tags: support

I just tried to log in to superuser.com with Lynx. When trying to log in with my StackExchange account, it first gives a `HTTP 418` message `I'm a teapot` and then

> Sorry, your request could not be completed because it looked
>      suspicious. If you meant to perform an action on Super User, please
>      return to the previous page and try again.

Is it generally unwanted to log in with Lynx or might this be a bug?

Comment: +1 for a reference to [RFC 2324](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2324).

Comment: See also: [Login using the Lynx browser](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183740/login-using-the-lynx-browser) [Browsing using lynx and links (text-only browser)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31069/browsing-using-lynx-and-links-text-only-browser) and [Column 80 - Plain Text optimised SOFU](http://stackapps.com/questions/542/column-80-plain-text-optimised-sofu) for a better (read-only) Lynx experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lynx is not in the [list of supported browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need).

You can probably read Stack Exchanges sites just fine, but login is not expected to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I'm sorry for the question. It turns out I searched for Lynx on superuser instead of meta superuser. Otherwise I would probably have found the answer myself...

Comment: Don't worry about it—next time somebody searches for Lynx here, they'll find something!